# Adding docBase in Eclipse tomcat server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

i tried adding a new docbase into server.xml in order to define a upload directory within my tomcat sever. Hoever if i add this to my standalone tomcat server it works like a charm:

```
<Context docBase="C:\uploads" path="/uploads" reloadable="true" />
```

But within my local eclipse tomcat server config it does not work. My puplishing action is to "update context paths" and i use the "workspace metadata" in the servers tab.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the "it does not work"

Comment: What i mean is that i can not access any file stores in the upload directory when i run it from my eclipse env.

Comment: I've just tested and I'm having an error in the tomcat startup logs indicating that it is trying to change the document base to an upload folder in the eclipse workspace and not in c:. Can you please check if you have the same error.

Comment: Thanks for your support! I will report you later as soon i am back home. As of now to me it seems like tomcat in eclipse runs slightly different when it comes to docbase configs.

Comment: Finally i could try to check it. When i start tomcat from eclipse i do not see such a error. Tomcat simply starts fine but the directory is not accessible. Is your tomcat setup in eclipse. What is checked under (Servers->Server Properties->Server Locations)? For me its  the first option "Use wokrspace metadata..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solved my issue:

I created a new server in eclipse and set the "Server Locations" to

"Use Tomcat installation (take control of Tomcat installation)"

Using this option in eclipse uses by default the wtpwebapps as deployment path. It also respects now the newly added docbase in server.xml.

Cheers!